# React, node js, mongoDB - How to make post, put, delete with FormData?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, fetch, axios

How to create a post service with formdata?

I sent formdata by Axios.
However, the value of 'req.body.title' on the node-express server is empty.
So now I am sending fetch in the following format.
But I need to upload the file to the server, so I want to send it using formData.

```js
let bodys = 'title=a1&contents=b'
fetch("http://localhost:5000/test", {
            method : 'post',
            headers : {
                'Content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            },
            body: bodys
        })
        .then(function(response){
            console.log('Request Succeded ', response);
        })
        .catch(function (error){
            console.log('Failed ', error)
        })
```

I wrote new data using append with new FormData(),
I checked that FormData contains a value on React.
However, the node-express server did not enter the body.

please let me know what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending FormData object instead of raw string as your request body.

```
const bodys = new FormData();

bodys.append('title', 'a1');
bodys.append('contents', 'b');
```

This form data will be available in request.body  in express.js server.

Edit: to parse the FormData in express.js, you need a middleware like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)

```
const upload = require('multer');

app.use('/', upload.any(), yourRouteHandler);
```

Comment: As oosniss points out, you'll need some middleware that parses `multipart/form-data`. Libraries, like bodyParser, do not handle this MIME type and therefore form data won't show up on `req.body`.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending just a string so

You can access your body like below

```
  let bodys = 'title=a1&contents=b'
 console.log(req.body); //will print title and contents as you are sending
```

If you want to access title and contents separately then you have to send data as an object

```
  const bodys = {“title”: “a1”, “contents”: “b”}
  console.log(“title”, req.body.title); //will print a1
  console.log(“contents”, req.body.contents); //will print b
```

Chec this thread for more details https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/263